# opengl don't call glClear() in render

Tags: opengl, jogl

I draw GLUT primitives each render, more and more. To make things faster, I decided not to clear every time, just put new primitives. Is that just wrong?

When I did this, I got blinking. Putting sleep() showed that one frame is ok and second is empty and so on.

EDIT:
Brief code in render(display) that is executed once(I use Java's JOGL):

```
gl.glPushMatrix(); 
gl.glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
glut.glutSolidCube(10);
gl.glPopMatrix();
drawable.swapBuffers();
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you're working with here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is empty.When you clear, you clear the front buffer frame.Then , when swapBuffers() called the back-buffer frame becomes front , and in the meanwhile your stuff is being drawn to the front buffer frame ,which just has become back-buffer frame.Then ,when the backbuffer frame is finished the buffer swap is done(triggered by the call to swapBuffers().That is how double buffering works.If you don't clear the frame color you will get your drawings accumulated in the front buffer over time ,which I am not sure is desired result.
Clearing the front buffer once in the beginning of every render loop is not a big performance hit.The problem appears when you call glClear() frequently ,like calling it before each object drawing which also doesn't make sense as  in such a case you will see only the last drawn object.
For the flickering - you should be more descriptive on how you do it all.From your example it is unclear why it happens.

Comment: Many thanks. I did my drawing twice and there's no more flickering. But it seems that gluLookAt() is not working correctly without glClear(), so I'm going to use glClear() as it's the easiest way.

Comment: gluLookAt() shouldn't be related to glClear().glClear clears pixels.gluLookAt does math.If you post here more code then may be we can help you with this...

Answer (score 0):

```
gl.glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

?

It's hard to say without seeing more of your code.

When ever I get unexpected results in openGL code, I mentally go through the list of state possibilities and set them either enabled or disabled:

- Depth Test
- Texturing
- Lighting
- Blending
- Culling
- Framebuffers
- Shaders

Answer (score 0):

Swapbuffers(HDC) doesn't actually copy the contents of the buffer but merely swaps the front and back buffer, that is why you see every odd frame, but not the even ones.